# Rendering pictures in email's template in Meteor

Tags: email, templates, meteor

I have and nice email template stored in /private folder and I have some pictures in /public/images folder. I have img tags with links to my template using full path (http://localhost:3000/images/image1) or external links.
I render my template using

```
SSR.compileTemplate('myTemplate',Assets.getText('myTemplate.html');
renderedTemplate = SSR.render('myTemplate',emailData);
    var dataContext = {
        htmlHead: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">',
        htmlFoot: '</html>'
    };
```

and then I use

```
    finalHtml = dataContext.htmlHead + renderedHtml + dataContext.htmlFoot;
    Email.send({
       from: smtp.login,
       to: email,
       subject: 'News',
       html: finalHtml
    });
```

Then when I get my lovely mail everything is nice and perfect but my attached images which are not loaded;is it a problem with SSR.compileTemplate? Usually static pictures should be attached at the bottom of email (if I check the "show original" in my gmail) but they are not there..
What am I doing wrong and how I should solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Meteor.absoluteUrl` method is the proper way to reference an image source. However, I believe you will still face the same problem even after using it.

This is because you are trying to reference an image from a *non-publicly* accessible url. Which in your case `localhost` will be the **host** in your full path to your image. Your html template needs to reference the images to a specific uri. In this case, it won't be able because it's been hosted on your local machine.

If you deploy your app on a hosted environment, your host url will be served up. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Great! let me know how it goes and if all is good please upvote and mark as answered please!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Meteor.absoluteUrl`, see docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl).

Maybe something like:

```
emailData.absoluteUrl = Meteor.absoluteUrl('/');
```

Then in your template:

```
<img src="{{absoluteUrl}}/path-to-your-image.jpg"/>
```

Haven't tried it myself, so this is untested. I tend to use assets direct from S3.